# Returning Json string from oracle procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I need to have a stored procedure in PL/SQL that return a string containing a json object.
This object must be a list of object representing rows a table.

For example I have the table
`MY_TABLE(ID, TB_VALUE)`

The output must be :

```json
[
  {
    "id":"1",
    "value":"valueTest"
  },
  {
    "id":"2",
    "value":"valueTest2"
  },
  {
    "id":"3",
    "value":"valueTest3"
  }
]
```

My stored procedure looks like that :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY "PKG_GETCOR" AS

PROCEDURE SelectProc(output OUT VARCHAR2) IS 
v_json_start CHAR(1) := '[';
v_json_end CHAR(1) := ']';
l_first_rec BOOLEAN := TRUE;

BEGIN
    output := v_json_end;
FOR output IN (SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE)
LOOP
    IF NOT l_first_rec
    THEN
        output := output || ',';
    END IF;
    output := output || JSON_OBJECT('id' VALUE ID, 'value' VALUE TB_VALUE));
END LOOP;   
output := output || (v_json_end); 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(output);

END SelectProc;

END PKG_GETCOR;
```

What's the best way to achieve this ?
Should I use DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ?

Comment: You output is invalid JSON as the array has a trailing comma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Oracle 12, you do not need a procedure or to create your own JSON functions.

```sql
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(
         JSON_OBJECT( KEY 'id' VALUE id, KEY 'value' VALUE tb_value )
         FORMAT JSON
         ORDER BY id
         RETURNING CLOB
       ) AS json
FROM   my_table;
```

Outputs:

> | JSON |
> | --- |
> | [{"id":1,"value":"valueTest"},{"id":2,"value":"valueTest2"},{"id":3,"value":"valueTest3"}] |

---

If you really want it in a package then convert it to a function and just wrap the query:

```sql
CREATE PACKAGE PKG_GETCOR AS
  FUNCTION SelectFunc RETURN CLOB;
END;
/

CREATE PACKAGE BODY PKG_GETCOR AS

  FUNCTION SelectFunc RETURN CLOB
  IS 
    v_json CLOB;
  BEGIN
    SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(
             JSON_OBJECT( KEY 'id' VALUE id, KEY 'value' VALUE tb_value )
             FORMAT JSON
             ORDER BY id
             RETURNING CLOB
           )
    INTO   v_json
    FROM   my_table;
    
    RETURN v_json;
  END SelectFunc;
END PKG_GETCOR;
/
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT pkg_getcor.selectfunc() FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | PKG_GETCOR.SELECTFUNC() |
> | --- |
> | [{"id":1,"value":"valueTest"},{"id":2,"value":"valueTest2"},{"id":3,"value":"valueTest3"}] |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d522aac50a2c1286fcd7cfc892b83ea1)*

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Thanks for the edit; however, `JSON_ARRAYAGG` does not pretty-print the output so I am returning the output to the actual value.

Comment: Perfect Answer, it's working great this way !

Answer (score 1):

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE is meant to be used for debugging and shouldn't show up in user's applications.

If you wish to display it, you can change that procedure into a function or give the procedure an out parameter and then read that.

Turn it into a function, put the json into a clob, return it and then call it like:

```
SELECT SelectProc() FROM DUAL;
```